# Can I change/fix the way Matlab creates text boxes in an eps

Tags: matlab, eps

If I export my matlab figure as an eps using:

```
print('myfig','-depsc')
```

I then open it in another software, in my case Illustrator CS6. 
The text appears ok, but what should be a single text box, say a legend entry, is actually multiple text boxes arranged so that it looks like one. 
In the image below, the black text is what it looks like  first, but I have also shown a copy of the same text, with each text box a different color. [image]

If I want to edit any of this its very difficult as the space will then be messed up. Also if I change the font, the kerning gets messed up. 
I have also tried using the text command to place text on the axis, and this also ends up in multiple text boxes.

Is there any way to fix this? 
Am I missing something?

Just to be clear, I would like to fix matlab's eps, Not use a different software.

Comment: Try `export_fig` from FEX.

Comment: Thanks @AnderBiguri, if possible I want to avoid 3rd party things as this code needs to be usable for other people. In order to make an eps in export_fig, you need pdftops installed.

Comment: If your figure data is managable, then switch to `pgfplots` and you will not even remember about these problems

Comment: @percusse I am trying to stay within Matlab for now. As I can do my calculations and plotting together. At the minute I'd prefer not to replace matlab as my plotting tool.

Comment: Depends on what you do with the resulting eps file. If it goes to a TeX file then you don't change anything in your workflow

Comment: @percusse no, these figures need to go into illustrator for other annotations etc. The final use isn't TeX either.

Comment: have you tried saving as `.svg` instead and open in illustrator ?

Comment: @bla yes I have tried, but svg gives me the text as a shape, not as an editable text.